# Drop SCHEMABINDING from all views in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to recreate all views without `SCHEMABINDING`, but when I create the script with `syscomments`, the `text` column contains `CREATE VIEW` instead of `ALTER VIEW`. How can I generate an `ALTER` script?

Comment: As an aside, you really shouldn't use `syscomments` - this is a deprecated, backward-compatibility view that will eventually disappear - [please see the note in the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx). Get familiar with the new catalog views such as [`sys.procedures`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx) and [`sys.sql_modules`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx), and metadata functions like [`OBJECT_DEFINITION()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to highlight the Views node in Object Explorer, then hit <kbd>F7</kbd> (`View > Object Explorer Details`). On the right will be all of the views; unfortunately you can't filter or add a new column to sort based on whether the view does have `SCHEMABINDING`. So you'll have to manually select the ones you want (or just select all except the `System Views` folder), then right-click, `Script View As > DROP and CREATE to > New Query Editor Window`. Now you can just search that script for `SCHEMABINDING`, delete or comment out each instance, and then run the script. If some of the views you selected did not have `SCHEMABINDING` in the first place, then no big deal - they'll just get dropped and re-created too.

(This is much easier, in my opinion, than trying to search and replace `CREATE VIEW` with `ALTER VIEW` - since there could be any number of whitespace characters between `CREATE` and `VIEW`, and you'll still have to comment or remove the `SCHEMABINDING`. Though it might not hurt, as part of this exercise, to ensure that the syntax conventions here are consistent, and fix views that don't adhere, e.g. changing `CREATE______VIEW` to `CREATE_VIEW` (underscores to represent spaces).)

Note that this will obviously delete any indexes that are associated with these views.

Also note that the [generate scripts wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245282.aspx) will also allow you to select all of the views, but not filter on whether they have `SCHEMABINDING`, and the wizard won't script `ALTER` but you can choose `DROP and CREATE` in Advanced settings. You'll still need to adjust the output to remove the `SCHEMABINDING` and, depending on options selected, you may need to remove any `CREATE INDEX` statements for indexed views that will now fail.